# Possible "Longboarding" tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I would suggest a [longboarding](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longboarding) tag to differentiate longboarding questions from skateboarding questions. I think it would just make it easier is all :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Request completed

Comment: This question's status is `completed`